# how to make random value in range a-z with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have python code which it will generate random values like

```
JAY5uFy4F
```

This is the first output when I run the python script.

This is my code:

```
a= []
n=1
c=1
c2=3
Start= 10**(n-1)
End= (10**n)-1
while 1 :
    Num= random.randint(Start,End)
    Text= string.ascii_letters
    txt=''.join(random.choice(Text) for i in range(c))
    txt2=''.join(random.choice(Text) for i in range(c2))

    def Value():
        V= random.randint(3,6)
        vl= (f"JAY{V}{txt2}{Num}{txt}")
        return (vl)
    passwd =Value()
    if (passwd) not in (a):
        a.append (passwd)
        print(a)
    else:
        break
```

I know the code above will generate the sentence "JAY..." randomly but what I want is to get [az][AZ] after the word "JAY..."

For example:

```
JAY5abc1d
JAY5bcd1e
JAY5cde1f
```

etc.
and also uppercase characters

```
JAY5Abc1d
JAY5Bcd1e
JAY5Cde1f
```

until z, then when it reaches the last character the number changes

```
JAY5Abc2d 
JAY5Bcd2e 
JAY5Cde2f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.product` to iterate deterministically, rather than using a randomized algorithm.

Something like would seem to do what you want:

```
import itertools
from string import ascii_letters

def make_options(n, c1, c2):
  parts = [
    ['JAY'],
    map(str, range(3, 7)),
    *([ascii_letters] * c1),
    map(str, range(10**(n-1), 10**n)),
    *([ascii_letters] * c2),
  ]
  for cs in itertools.product(*parts):
    yield ''.join(cs)
```

I'm using an iterator because this will be a **long** list, and trying to keep the whole thing in memory at once will probably fail.

If you keep your parameters in the small part of the space, you can easily get an array out of this by doing:

```
a = list(make_options(1, 1, 1))
```

but note that this is already 97k entries.

Comment: thanks!,this helps me to develop code again. although the way it works is a bit memory-intensive

Comment: note that your code would be just as memory intensive if it iterated over everything.  your code would tend to stop very early, see the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for more info.  but your `break` on first existing entry would be [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) to stop at the sqrt of total number of entries, so only after a few hundred entries with `a` above

Comment: okay, but how do you get the list above to become a complete array
like ["JAY1ab1cd"]

Comment: the `c1` and `c2` arguments control how many letters you want, like your code.  so you'd just call `list(make_options(1, 2, 2))`.  this gives ~18million combinations, so will take a while.